# Issue running apprtc on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I am following [instruction](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) and am able to build, run apprtc on my local ubuntu machine.

I am trying to implement the same on AWS. I have added ports 8000 and 8080 to the instance security group. On AWS when I execute

> /dev_appserver.py ./out/app_engine

I get console message

```
Starting API server at: http://localhost:45920
Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

I check ec2...compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000, ec2...compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080 and see nothing. Could you please point to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

By default the apprtc is bound to localhost, you need to specify --host 0.0.0.0 in order to expose it outside.

So use "/home/usertest/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py ./out/app_engine --host 0.0.0.0" to run out the machine